# Using ALM OTA, how do we know if an ALM Resource is checked out?

Tags: alm

I have a requirement to upload a modified Resource file into ALM Test Resources. Before uploading, I need to verify if the Resource is Checked out, if not I need to Checkout that Resource.

I need to perform all these actions using OTA. I am able to get the particular resource object, and able to checkout/checkin.

But, I am not able to get the Version Control status (checkedout/checkedin). I found from ALM OTA API Reference that IsCheckedOut property can give us this result, but I am not getting on how this property to be used. Below is my code -

```
objFilter.Filter("RSC_FOLDER_NAME") = QCResourceFolderPath
Set objResourcesList = objFilter.NewList
For Each Resource In objResourcesList
    If Resource.Name = strFileName Then
        Resource.VC.Checkout ""
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This piece of code is performing Checkout operation, but am not able to use IsCheckedOut Property here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer. below piece of code gives me the checkedout status

```
Resource.VersionData.IsCheckedOut
```

So my code would be like this -

```
objFilter.Filter("RSC_FOLDER_NAME") = QCResourceFolderPath
Set objResourcesList = objFilter.NewList
For Each Resource In objResourcesList
    If Resource.Name = strFileName Then
        If Not(Resource.VersionData.IsCheckedOut) Then
            Resource.VC.Checkout ""
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one more way to get the Check Out Status

`Resource("RSC_VC_STATUS") would give us the status as "Checked_In" or "Checked_Out"`

using which we can implement our logic